Seeking Advice on Balancing a Full-Time Job and Studying Computer Science
I’m starting university in two months to study computer science and have two job offers: one from Vodafone UK (work from home, 10,000) and another from Sutherland (on-site, 15,000). I’m planning to take these jobs as temporary positions until I graduate, mainly for some extra money. I’m looking for advice from those who have managed work and computer science studies. How did you balance both, and which option do you think is better given my situation? Any insights or experiences would be greatly appreciated!

Is this a UK university?

No actually, it's an Egyptian private university. And that work is related to the customer service field

Assuming you’ll be an undergraduate, an extra full time commitment seems counterproductive to me. Part time to support your school work would be, or used to be, pretty common.

How common is it for students in Egypt to have full time employment in addition? I know nothing about the system there.

It's not that common, but anyone would do that if they needed money to support their family by paying the tuition, because it's a bit expensive here to study at a good university.

I have no knowledge of what requirements and time commitments are involved in studying at Egyptian universities or taking on the jobs you mention. But, in general, university education can be a quite different and more demanding experience than what you might have experienced in the past, and take some time to adapt to. For this reason, the standard advice I've seen and given is to try it for at least a semester without additional obligations. Then you'll have a much better sense of what the degree programme demands of you, and what your capacity for work on the side is. Perhaps part-time employment is doable, but full-time isn't. Of course, not everyone can afford to do this, but your characterization of the side job as being "mainly for some extra money" suggests you might be able to. Also make sure to talk to students studying for the same degree - some semesters might be more busy than others.
We cannot judge the specific job offers, or which is more suitable for you. You know the offers better than we do. But in addition to aspects like pay, commute time and job conditions do consider whether there would be scheduling conflicts between classes/labs/exams with mandatory attendance and work hours. A more flexible employer can make it easier to finish a degree on time or with better grades and knowledge, which might matter a lot more long-term than a slight pay bump in a temporary position.

I also do not know any specifics on higher education in Egypt, but in my experience most undergrad programmes world-wide are intended to be full-time.
While the amount of scheduled coursework (i.e. timetabled lectures, workshops, and the like) may vary greatly, total amount of work expected per module (timetabled+independent) is usually quite high.
As an example, most single-semester undergrad modules in the UK are worth 15 credits, which translates to ~150 hours total over 12 timetabled weeks; in addition to the 4h a week of timetabled sessions, this means that the expectation is that the student works an additional 8.5h/week on this module. You would typically have 4 such modules per semester, and therefore be expected to put in approximately additional 34 hours of independent work weekly in addition to attending all your timetabled sessions (10-16h/week). I believe UK considers any employment of over 32h/week as full-time, so this is essentially equivalent or more than a full time job.
While I don't have any hard statistics at hand, due to a harsh increase in cost of living, we have recently observed an increase in the number of students taking up work in addition to the University (and an increase in the number of hours they spend at work), and this has correlated pretty strongly (and negatively) with student success and pass rates. Essentially, in my experience, the more work that the students do outside of their study programme, the lower their grades are, and the lower their chances of completing the programme in the first place.
Most success stories about working while studying actually come from mature students (by which I mean, anybody not-straight-out-of-secondary-education). As mature students usually have a much clearer idea as to why they decided to get a degree, they are prepared for more sacrifices. If they need to take up work with their studies (i.e. to keep the living standard of their family, or pay their mortgage), they have usually taken this into account and have accepted sacrifices. However, do note that even in the "success stories" I have heard about, the sacrifice tends to be pretty high - as healthy habits, exercise, healthy diet, social life, and family life all sometimes end up being sacrificed in order to keep up with studying and working full time.

Just like all the the others, I know nothing about work or education in Egypt. But I will give my two cents and experience.
I worked part time from the first semester of Bachelor, but I started to work full time only once I started my PhD (after I finished my Master's). Therefore, if we are talking about part-time, it is definitely doable, countless students do it, especially in fields like CS. Actually, I have found that not having enough time really forced me not to procrastinate, so in the end, the day did not get that much shorter. Saying that, working full-time from the absolute beginning (so I assume you are around 18yo) sounds pretty rough, assuming the school does not make attendance mandatory, otherwise it is pretty much impossible. But I don't know you, so it might not be a problem for you. I was too lazy to do that.
No idea what the jobs are about, but I found 2 features of a job where you can save a lot of time, which really helped me during my studies:

A lot of manual work (e.g., checking the same excel sheets every day, downloading bunch of files ...) that you can automatize using few lines of python.

Deadlines rather than hours. If you don't have to be at work from X to Y, but you are rather expected to meet some deadlines, you can work much more efficiently and you can somewhat choose when it is better to work.


Few more points:

If possible, avoid commute as much as possible. Commute can get pretty exhausting and tiresome. It also can eat a lot of your time.
Do everything as early as possible. Easy and obvious advice, but it is really important. Trying to resolve 5 things that all need to be done until the end of week instead of sleeping is not fun.
Don't drink, or at least, don't waste your time partying.

